# How to parse a dynamically updating webpage in C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, webbrowser-control

I am trying to parse the number shown in this page:

https://www.edf.org/embed/methane-counters

I have tried WebBrowser, WebClient ... etc. with no good result.  Every time I try something new, in the HTML returned I get this (HTML area where the number is shown):

```
<strong id=\"methane\"></strong>
```

... as you see there is no number between the 'strong' tags.  Just in case, this is the latest code I have tried, that still do not work:

```
using (WebBrowser myWebBrowser = new WebBrowser()) {
    myWebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    myWebBrowser.Navigate(myURL);

    while ((myWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)) 
        Application.DoEvents();

    myContent = myWebBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
    myContent = myWebBrowser.DocumentText;
}
```

... neither of the last two calls returns the HTML with the number on it.

Any ideas on how to get the proper content of this page?

Comment: The number is updated via JS, so it won't be inside the HTML. What you are getting is just the tag where the JS will update the number. *What* are you trying to achieve by parsing a number that is changed every second?

Comment: There most be an HTML equivalent where the number is placed after the JS runs.  What I need is to get the page after the JS runs at least just once.  I want to go regularly to that page and grab the number for other calculations I am doing, I can still go and get it every 15 minutes for example.  The request is valid.